# I can't see generated random number

Tags: html, variables, random, types, batch-file

I wrote this script to combine more html file. I used the random function for a part of that. I see a strange thing...

```
@echo on 
pause
CD "C:\Documents and Settings\Mauro\Documenti\Firme\ProvaMerge\"
pause
for %%i in (Pasqualino,Mauro) DO (
pause
ECHO %%i 
pause
type Parti_Standard\StrutturaTabella_1parte.txt > %%i.html
pause
type utenti\%%i.html >> %%i.html
pause
type Parti_Standard\StrutturaTabella_2parte.txt >>%%i.html
:loop
set /a photo=%random% %% 3 + 1 
ECHO RANDOM
ECHO %random% %%PHOTO
TYPE Immagini\%photo%.txt >> %%i.html
pause
type Parti_Standard\StrutturaTabella_3parte.txt >> %%i.html
type Firme_Standard\"Firma Inox Pack.html" >> %%i.html
)
pause
```

All is OK but I don't see `%photo%` variable... I tried with `%%photo` or `%photo%` but I obtain only a null variable. Instead first to improve the complexity of that script, I was using it without the for loop there... And It works fine.

```
@echo on 
CD "C:\Documents and Settings\Mauro\Documenti\Firme\ProvaMerge\"
type Parti_Standard\StrutturaTabella_1parte.txt >new.html
type mauro.html >> new.html
type Parti_Standard\StrutturaTabella_2parte.txt >>new.html
:loop
set /a photo=%random% %% 3 + 1 
echo %%photo
pause
TYPE Immagini\%photo%.txt >> new.html
type Parti_Standard\StrutturaTabella_3parte.txt >> new.html
type Firme_Standard\"Firma Inox Pack.html" >>new.html
pause
```

Why?

Comment: i don't understand sorry? I tryed with only one % but it's the same...

Comment: Have you tried using EnableDelayedExpansion and using !photo! for your variable?

Comment: I add   Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion   and !photo! . Now i see with echo the random number generated but it doesn't pick my file and write it to the new...

Answer (score 0):

Inside a codeblock (eg. a for loop) you need `delayed expansion`. Example, this doesn't work:

```
@echo off&setlocal
(
set /a photo=%random% %% 3 + 1 
echo %photo%
)
```

.. and this works:

```
@echo off&setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
(
set /a photo=!random! %% 3 + 1 
echo !photo!
)
```

This must aso be used to write to a file:

```
TYPE Immagini\!photo!.txt >> %%i.html
```

Comment: I put !! also in type... When I try with "echo !photo!" I see written echo !photo! and not the generated number. Then also "type !photo!.txt and not 1.txt or 2 or 3... The I press any key, the script goes on, i see the name of the file generated, then i press again and only now i can see the generated number.. but it's too late to include to take that... I can't post an image to make you understand... ma parli italiano?

Answer (score 0):

oK now it work! Thank you!!

```
@echooff
pause
CD "C:\Documents and Settings\Mauro\Documenti\Firme\ProvaMerge\"
for %%i in (Pasqualino,Mauro) DO (
for %%g in ("Firma Inox Pack","Firma Mail Arca Cucine") Do (
pause
ECHO "%%i %%g".html 
type Parti_Standard\StrutturaTabella_1parte.txt > Firme_Composte\%%i\"%%i %%g".html
type utenti\%%i.html >> Firme_Composte\%%i\"%%i %%g".html
type Parti_Standard\StrutturaTabella_2parte.txt >> Firme_Composte\%%i\"%%i %%g".html
pause
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
(
set /a n=!random! %% 3 + 1 
echo !n!
)
TYPE Immagini\!n!.txt >> Firme_Composte\%%i\"%%i %%g".html
pause
type Parti_Standard\StrutturaTabella_3parte.txt >> Firme_Composte\%%i\"%%i %%g".html
type Firme_Standard\%%g.html >> Firme_Composte\%%i\"%%i %%g".html 
)
)
```